# NSMutableArray initialize and destroy values

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray

i'm creating an Xcode app and i need to create an `NSMutableArray` that gets initialized when my switch are on and when a switch is off the value assigned to the switch that was also assigned to the NSMutableArray gets destroyed from the Array, how the code should be? I already initialized my switch but i don't know how to add/destroy the values from the NSMUtableArray

Comment: That's a very general question and therefore you won't get a very focused answer.

Comment: ye i know but i can't be more specific i think.. I just want to know how to add or remove a value from an NSMutableArray becaause i don't know how to use them

Comment: You will need to attempt a solution and post back with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)changeState:(id)sender 
{
    UICustomSwitch* currentSwitch = (UICustomSwitch*)sender;
    if ([currentSwitch isOn]) {
        [myMutableArray addObject:currentSwitch.myCustomValue];
    } else {
        [myMutableArray removeObject:currentSwitch.myCustomValue];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have to add new object in NSMutableArray

```
ringsArray.addObject(_ring)
```

if insert object within NSMutableArray

```
ringsArray.insertObject("Value", atIndex: position)
```

Same as work on remove value

```
ringsArray.removeObject("")
ringsArray.removeObjectAtIndex(position)
```